# Compare Two Sheets (A and B): Copied data from Sheet A creates duplication in Sheet B

Tags: excel, compare

In breaking down my original problem, I have come to this road block: some is being copied from the first sheet (A) to second sheet (B) when I run compare code.

I am comparing row A in Summary sheet against row B in Tutoring sheet and copying differences (new data) to (B). The problem is when I run the code, some of the values from row A Summary are repeated in Tutoring (B) while some data is not copied at all.

The names in Yellow should be the ones added, but when I run the code, some data is copied over which causes a duplication of data in Sheet B.

Here is the Summary Sheet, the new data is hilighted in yellow, which should be the only data copied over to Tutoring sheet (B)

[image: Summary Sheet Example].

Here is the Tutoring Sheet which shows the old data (in green) the new data (in yellow) and the duplicated data circled in red):

[image: Tutoring Sheet (Failed Report]

Here is my code which I have struggled with for days:

```vb
    Private Sub Find_Match_Summary()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")              ' Column A  relates to a = row 4  and i = 4
    a = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row      ' Last filled cell in Column A of Summary
    i = 4                                               ' Beginning row of compare for Summary

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tutoring Attendance")  ' Column B  relates to b  = row 5  and j =5
    b = ws2.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row      ' Last filled cell in Column B of Tutoring
    j = 5                                               ' Beginning row of compare for Tutoring

For i = 4 To a
    
    ws1.Activate
    ws1.Range(i, 1).Select                              ' Select first cell to compare
    If Trim(ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value2) = Trim(ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value2) Then
        MsgBox "Cells are True for = " & ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value2
            
    Else
        ws1.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Copy                    ' Copy the two cells of data
        ws2.Activate                                        ' Tutoring Sheet
        b = ws2.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row      ' Last filled cell in Column B of Tutoring
        ws2.Cells(b + 1, 2).Select                          ' First empty cell in Column B of Tutoring
        ws2.Range("B50").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Paste VALUES only to new rows
        MsgBox "Verify " & ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value2 & " was copied over"    ' Used to verify correct Value was copied over
    End If
    
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ws1.Activate  ' Tutoring Attendance sheet activated

MsgBox "Find_Match_Summary - Done!"

End Sub
```

Please see what you can do to assist me in finding my errors of my code.

Thanks folks for your help!